# How to override Equals on a class that has a child collection

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a parent and child class like this and want to be able to compare 2 instances with the same property values

```
    public class Person
    { 
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object? obj)
        {
            return obj is Person person &&
                   Name == person.Name &&
                   EqualityComparer<List<Address>>.Default.Equals(Addresses, person.Addresses);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return HashCode.Combine(Name, Addresses);
        }
    }

    public class Address
    { 
        public string StreetName { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object? obj)
        {
            return obj is Address address &&
                   StreetName == address.StreetName;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return HashCode.Combine(StreetName);
        }
    }
```

the equality checks fails when I try compare 2 identical objects eg

```
var person = new Person() 
{
        Name = "Mr Test", 
        Addresses = new List<Address>()
        {
            new Address()
            {
                StreetName = "Test Street" 
            }
        }
};

var person2 = new Person()
{
    Name = "Mr Test",
    Addresses = new List<Address>()
        {
            new Address()
            {
                StreetName = "Test Street"
            }
        }
};

var result = person.Equals(person2);
```

result is false, the issue seems to be to do with the comparison of the child Address collection items.

what do I have to do to implement this correctly?

Comment: Even if in both the Addresses are filled equally GetHashcode of those List will be different.  You need to implement a fitting Hashcode Algo for Addresses that actual looks in its content.

Comment: If you override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` you are ***strongly*** advised to make your objects immutable.

Comment: For Equals itself use `Addresses.SequenceEqual(person.Addresses);` instead of using the EqualityComparer.

Comment: @Ralf - That doesn't deal with the case that the addresses are out of order. That might be important when it comes to addresses.

Comment: @Enigmativity He didn't defined that but yeah maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement IEquatable<> in the Person class or use record type instead of class

```
    public class Person : IEquatable<Person>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object? obj)
        {
            return obj is Person person &&
                   Name == person.Name &&
                   EqualityComparer<List<Address>>.Default.Equals(Addresses, person.Addresses);
        }

        public bool Equals(Person other)
        {
            // equality code here
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return HashCode.Combine(Name, Addresses);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Default equality comparison for reference types is object reference: are they the same object. As `List<T>` does not implement any overrides of the default that is what you are getting. You will only get equality if the two lists are the same object.

You will need to (I assume: the semantics are up to you) iterate through the collections to check item by item.

(This makes sense: there are too many reasonable ways to compare two indexed collections to have a default.)

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing references, `Address`/`person.Address` which is false. You'll have to iterate through the arrays and establish equilibrium.

Comment: Which is correct? "equilibrium" or "equality"? Equilibrium has the sense that both side are being modified until reach equality.

Comment: My bad, was in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using immutable properties and `ImmutableHashSet<>` to correctly create an object that is durable when using `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
        = String.Empty;

    public ImmutableHashSet<Address> Addresses { get; init; }
        = ImmutableHashSet.Create<Address>();

    public override bool Equals(object? obj) =>
        obj is Person person
        && this.Name == person.Name
        && this.Addresses.SetEquals(person.Addresses);
            
    public override int GetHashCode() =>
        HashCode.Combine(Name, Addresses);
}

public class Address
{
    public string StreetName { get; init; }
        = String.Empty;

    public override bool Equals(object? obj) =>
        obj is Address address
        && this.StreetName == address.StreetName;

    public override int GetHashCode() =>
        HashCode.Combine(this.StreetName);
}
```

Now you can write your code as such:

```
var person = new Person()
{
    Name = "Mr Test",
    Addresses = ImmutableHashSet.CreateRange<Address>(new []
    {
        new Address() { StreetName = "Test Street" },
    }),
};

var person2 = new Person()
{
    Name = "Mr Test",
    Addresses = ImmutableHashSet.CreateRange<Address>(new[]
    {
        new Address() { StreetName = "Test Street" },
    }),
};

bool result = person.Equals(person2);
```

That produces `true`.

Comment: Not actually used but i think that ImmutableHashSet also has no GetHashcode implementation so here GetHashode will be different even if Equals returns true.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something like this; making use of the IEqualityComparer interface

```
    public class Person : IEquatable<Person>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(Person? other)
        {
            if (Name == other.Name)
            {
                return (AddressEquals(other.Addresses, Addresses));
            }
            return false;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return HashCode.Combine(Name, Addresses);
        }

        private bool AddressEquals(List<Address> address1, List<Address> addresses2)
        {
            var firstNotSecond = address1.Except(addresses2, new AddressComparer()).ToList();
            var secondNotFirst = addresses2.Except(address1, new AddressComparer()).ToList();

            return (!firstNotSecond.Any() && !secondNotFirst.Any());
        }
    }
```

and implemented an equality comparer for the address class.

```
    public class AddressComparer : IEqualityComparer<Address>
    {
        public bool Equals(Address? x, Address? y)
        {
            return x.StreetName == y.StreetName;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Address obj)
        {
            return HashCode.Combine(obj.StreetName);
        }
    }
```

you can then create a couple of instances of Person with some populated Addresses and call

```
    var result = person.Equals(person2);
```